# Calculate the joint distribution of $X, Y$ and $Z$, following a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ follow a bivariate normal distribution with $\mu = (0,0)^T$, $\sigma_x=1$, $\sigma_y=1$ and correlation $\rho =0.5$. Also, suppose that a pair $Z$ and $Y$ follow a bivariate normal distribution with $\mu = (0,0)^T$, $\sigma_z=1$ and $Cov(Y,Z) =0$. Now I would like to calculate the joint distribution of $X, Y$ and $Z$ if $X = \rho Y + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z$

**My thoughts**

The joint probability for $X$ and $Y$ is $$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}(1-\rho_{12}^2})}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho_{12}^2)}\left[\left(\frac{x_1-\mu_1}{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x_2-\mu_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}}\right)^2-2\rho_{12}\left(\frac{x_1-\mu_1}{\sqrt{\sigma_{11}}}\right)\left(\frac{x_2-\mu_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_{22}}}\right)\right]\right)}$$
But how can I use this to calculate the joint distribution of $X, Y$ and $Z$? That's where I get stuck.

Comment: Work out the covariance matrix of the triple $(X,Y,Z)$. They are jointly  Gaussian, with mean 0, so you should be able to read the answer off. Note the distribution is supported on a 2 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, so there will not be a density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$COV(x,z)=COV(\rho y+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}z,z)=\rho COV(y,z)+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}COV(z,z)=\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$, so the covariance matrix is 
\begin{align}\Sigma=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho & \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\\
\rho & 1 & 0\\
\sqrt{1-\rho^2} & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The joint distribution is $N(\boldsymbol{0},\Sigma)$.